# Phoenix: How to Write Nested Conditions with with in the create action?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a transaction form that needs conditions to be met before saving. For example, it requires to have a matching customer PIN, reference number, seller code, etc. Some requirements are needed by some transaction types, others are not.

For example, X transactions just need a PIN, Y transactions need a PIN and reference, Z needs PIN and seller code, etc.

I assume that it would need a lot of conditionals which will be placed in the create action:

```
def create(conn, %{"transaction" => transaction_params}) do
  case Accounts.create_transaction(transaction_params) do
    {:ok, transaction} ->

      ## In Ruby it would be as simple with state machine as:

      if @transaction.x?
        if @transaction.pin == @user.pin
          @transaction.go!
        else
          @transaction.error1!
        end
      elsif @transaction.y?
        if @transaction.pin == @user.pin && @transaction.ref == @item.ref
          @transaction.go!
        else 
          @transaction.error2!
        end        
      ...


      conn
      |> redirect(to: Routes.transaction_path(conn, :show, transaction))

      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} -> render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
end
```

They say that `with` is supposed to be used. But it seems a lot more complicated than Ruby `if else`. How should the above nested conditions be written with `with`? Or is there any easier alternative to `with`?

Comment: `@transaction.x?` is something unexpected in [tag:elixir] code. Is `@transaction`’s value a module? Or what? Could you please post a less contrived example if you want to receive a less abstract response? The most important thing is what `@transaction` module attribute actually contains?

Comment: It's Ruby code. I used `if then` in Elixir as my answer instead.

Comment: There are some good examples here: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1

Answer (score 0):

`with` was too complicated so I just used `if then if then`

```
def create(conn, %{"transaction" => transaction_params}) do
  case Accounts.create_transaction(transaction_params) do
    {:ok, transaction} ->
      if transaction.type == "x" do
        user = Users.get_user!(transaction.user_id)
        if transaction.pin == user.pin do
          conn
          |> redirect(to: Routes.transaction_path(conn, :show, transaction))
        else 
          conn
            |> put_flash(:info, "Wrong PIN!")          
            |> redirect(to: "/")                        
        end
      else 
        if transaction.type == "y" do    
          user = Users.get_user!(transaction.user_id)
          product = Product.get_product!(transaction.product_id)   
          if transaction.pin == user.pin and transaction.ref == product.ref do
            conn
            |> redirect(to: Routes.transaction_path(conn, :show, transaction))
          else 
            conn
              |> put_flash(:info, "Wrong!")          
              |> redirect(to: "/")                        
          end
        else
          if transaction.type == "z" do
          ...
          end    
        end
      end

    {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} -> 
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Some error!")                  
      |> redirect(to: "/")        
  end
end
```

Comment: This is obviously not the use case for `with/1`. It suits well not for the many branches dependent on conditions, but for the railway monadic correct path, needed to terminate once something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with neither nested `if`s nor `with` statements. I would go with pattern matching, at least on the top level, validating a transaction type

```elixir
def create(conn, %{"transaction" => transaction_params}) do
  case Accounts.create_transaction(transaction_params) do
    {:ok, %{type: "x"} = transaction} ->
      user = Users.get_user!(transaction.user_id)
      if transaction.pin == user.pin do
        redirect(conn, to: Routes.transaction_path(conn, :show, transaction))
      else 
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Wrong PIN!")          
        |> redirect(to: "/")                        
      end
    {:ok, %{type: "y"} = transaction} ->
      user = Users.get_user!(transaction.user_id)
      product = Product.get_product!(transaction.product_id)   
      if transaction.pin == user.pin and transaction.ref == product.ref do
        redirect(conn, to: Routes.transaction_path(conn, :show, transaction))
      else 
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Wrong!")          
        |> redirect(to: "/")                        
      end
    {:ok, %{type: "z"} = transaction} ->
      …
    {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} -> 
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Some error!")                  
      |> redirect(to: "/")        
  end
end
```

A further improvement would be to extract validations for different types into private functions.

```elixir
def create(conn, %{"transaction" => transaction_params}) do
  case Accounts.create_transaction(transaction_params) do
    {:ok, %{type: type} = transaction} ->
      case checker(type, transaction) do
        :ok ->
          redirect(conn, to: Routes.transaction_path(conn, :show, transaction))
        {:error, flash, path} ->
          conn
          |> put_flash(:info, flash)
          |> redirect(to: path)
      end
    {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} -> 
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Some error!")                  
      |> redirect(to: "/")        
  end
end

@spec checker(type :: binary(), transaction :: map()) :: 
        :ok | {:error, binary(), binary()}
defp checker("x", transaction) do
  user = Users.get_user!(transaction.user_id)
  if transaction.pin == user.pin,
    do: :ok,
    else: {:error, "Wrong PIN!", "/")
end
defp checker("y", transaction) do
  user = Users.get_user!(transaction.user_id)
  product = Product.get_product!(transaction.product_id)   
  if transaction.pin == user.pin and transaction.ref == product.ref,
    do: :ok,
    else: {:error, "Wrong!", "/")
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't get it to work so I went  with my simpler answer

Comment: Well, fwiw, nested `if` would have never passed my code review :)